# Doing fio testing and hotplug remove the SSD

Tags: performance, disk, fio

When disk is in use, ex: doing fio testing ( random write ), remove the PCIe SSD at the same time.

Should I expect there is no any I/O error since the system support hotplug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you remove the device which is accessed, you'll get an I/O error. Because trying to access a nonexistent device *is* an I/O error.

Hotplug guarantees that the removed device itself will not be damaged during the removal, and that the system will continue running flawlessly if it doesn't depend on this particular device (e.g. you can't remove disk where the system currently resides and stores its swap, but you can remove some auxiliary device).